# Can't change tab name on Joomla 2.5.8

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

So I have a problem with Joomla 2.5.8 when Im trying to change browser tab name. Tab name is good only on "main page" (localhost), but when I open any other page from menu (localhost/x) it always says *Web* on browser tab. I tried adding tab name through Joomla Menu manager, tried changing it in Global Configuration -> SEO, but it only gave me *Web - Web* tab name
Any help? 
[Here's a website if you need it](http://81.7.99.85/)

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust that in the "Menu Manager"  Just click on:

```
->Menu Manager
->(Select your menu, likely Main Menu)
->Select the menu item (page) you want to edit
->Click on "Page Display Options"
->Type your new page title in the "Browser Page Title" bar
->Click save
```

Also, you should update your Joomla, 2.5.8 is very old which will have security and performance fixes available if you update to the newest version.

See here:  https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Updating_from_an_existing_version

Comment: As I mentioned adding title through Menu Manager doesn't work for me and I can't update Joomla because the company I create this website for prefers 2.5.8 version of Joomla (didn't asked why)